# Creating SKU's based on multiple seed lists

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have a list of ,item numbers in one column.  I need to create a SKU based on each item number and a seed list of 59 sizes.  The list of sizes in currently the first 59 rows of the same column holding the item numbers.  Thus the first item number is A60.

It would be helpful if each completed SKU was entered beneath each root item number in a single column. Example:

```
Item number: 991820, 991870
Size: 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5
```

Result:

```
991820  
991820_7.0  
991820_7.5  
991820_8.0  
991820_8.5  
991870  
991870_7.0  
991870_7.5  
991870_8.0  
991870_8.5
```

With a total count of nearly 100k, this would be a painful experience via any method but a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Place the item number list in a single column by itself on one sheet, and the size list on another sheet (give each list a heading).  Make sure the file is saved to disk before continuing.

- Click `Data >> From Other Sources >> From Microsoft Query`. Select
  "Excel files" and click OK: browse and select your file.
- In the next dialog if you don't see the sheets from the file click `Options` and
  ensure all items under `Show` are checked (you need at least `Tables` and `System Tables`).
- Expand the sheet items and double-click each of your columns to move them over to `Columns in your query`
- Click `Next` then `OK` when you get the message about joining the tables.
- In the "Microsoft Query" dialog, click the `SQL` button on the toolbar and edit the SQL to something like:

  `SELECT 'Sheet1$'.A & '_' & 'Sheet2$'.B
   FROM 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\temp.xlsx'.'Sheet1$' 'Sheet$',
       'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\temp.xlsx'.'Sheet2$' 'Sheet2$'`
- Choose `File >> Return Data to Excel` and select where you want to put your results.

**Note** - you can extend this to >2 columns if you add a sheet for each set of values to be combined.